# Does sqlite C\C++ library keep DB file as Memory-mapped file? and is it possible to make it do so?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, memory-mapped-files

So I wonder how sqlite C/C++ API keeps opened DB: does it use Memory-mapped file? Or how to make it do so?

Comment: I don't think it does because it uses cache pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. Just search sqlite3.c for `CreateFileMapping`.

Comment: AFAIK, SQLite uses mmap only for the header in the WAL journals.
See also http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/5319/focus=5328 and http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/71553

Answer (score 0):

By default, SQLite uses memory mapping for shared memory file which only gets used in WAL journal mode. As per SQLite documentation https://sqlite.org/mmap.html, we can set PRAGMA mmap_size to force SQLite to use memory mapped file i/o in other modes as well. However, SQLite falls back to regular file i/o if it fails to map files in the memory.